# How to use the Homebrew installed git on Mac?

Tags: homebrew, git

I have installed the newest version of git (1.8.3) using homebrew but when I type

```
git --version
```

in my terminal, it prints:

```
git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)
```

What should I do to replace the old version of git with the new one?

Comment: # In Terminal, Install it 

``` brew install git ````

# In $HOME/.zshrc you need to add path to make it available

PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/git/libexec/git-core:$PATH"

# In Terminal reload it  
  
source ~/.zshrc
  
# Test it   



which git  
/usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git

Answer (score 175, accepted):

If on Intel, add

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```

if on ARM/M1, add

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:${PATH}"
```

in `~/.bash_profile` followed by

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

solved the problem for my user.

Comment: If you want the change persistent across users, you can move `/usr/local/bin` above `/usr/bin` in `/etc/paths`.

Comment: This is the solution proposed by Homebrew itself when running `brew doctor` to diagnose the issue

Comment: this answer should be updated with the KevinT proposed solution of defining `/etc/paths`. Defining only the "export" may not be enough, if `/usr/bin` has "precedence" over `/usr/local/bin` (from brew)...

Comment: "solved the problem." What was the problem?

Comment: Remember to restart terminal! Didn't occur to me until i saw Juan Diego Gonzales's comment below

Comment: @Souleiman: Restarting isn't necessary. `source ~/.bash_profile` will re-read that. Restarting is just probably faster/easier. :)

Comment: @BSeven "What should I do to replace the old version of git with the new one?", is the problem.

Comment: Do we know why adding /usr/local/bin in PATH fixes the problem? How does homebrew takes priority on xcode git?

Comment: @PriyaRanjanSingh: including `/usr/local/bin` in `PATH` *before* `/usr/bin` make every command find the version of `git` which is in `/usr/local/bin` *before* the one which is the standard Apple one in `/usr/bin`. And this version is the one installed by `Homebrew`.

Comment: `brew link --overwrite git` worked for me

Comment: For people using zsh instead of bash, add the following to .zprofile:

```eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"```

Answer (score 184):

## Status 2022

All the tricks mentioned here in several answers are not necessary anymore on Intel Macs running macOS Sierra or higher with the latest Homebrew. Forget `export PATH="..."` and modifications to `~/.bash_profile`.

You simply do

```
brew install git
```

and you're done.

To confirm, open a new terminal window/tab and type

```
git --version
```

Please don't forget to open a **new** window. Terminals that were open before you started to `install` will not inherit any changes.

Comment: For those that cannot get this to work, chances are your PATH is not set properly. If you run `brew doctor` it will tell you that your system paths take precedence over the homebrew ones. The output will also include how to fix it. E.g. by running `echo export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> .zshrc`

Comment: This only works on Intel macs where `/usr/local/bin` seems to be in `/etc/paths` now. It for sure does not work for ARM Macs where Homebrew binaries are installed in `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

Comment: "Please don't forget to open a **new** window. " was key. :)

Comment: Also, if you want to stay on the same window, just do a `source ~/.zshrc` to refresh environment.

Answer (score 56):

Ok, I'm ready to get serious about scm.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.5 (Apple Git-50.3)
```

Nope, that's not what I wanted. I <3 homebrew, so:

```
$ brew install git
```

All set?

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.5 (Apple Git-50.3)
```

Doh! (scratches head)

```
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

Ah, Apple's git is in /usr/bin, so it trumps the homebrew one. What to do?

(A) Just rename Apple's binary

(B) Let homebrew-managed one take precedence:

[edit PATH export e.g. in ~/.zshrc (oh-my-zsh + iTerm2 FTW! /tangent)]

[specifically: move /usr/local/bin/git: before /usr/bin:]

... and/or (e.g. to more broadly let homebrew stuff trump system installs, and have the precedence apply to all shells and users) also edit /etc/paths file, [moving /usr/local/bin above /usr/bin]

But assuming just the simplest / least invasive approach:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-apple
```

Did it work?

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

So far so good, now the moment of truth:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.2.1
```

w00t! :)
Time to go read http://git-scm.com ! :)

Comment: PS Rel to comments about risks of editing /usr/bin: IMHO it's NBD. (Tho I do like Global nomad's sugg. to do "sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/git /usr/bin/git" ... which ensures that anything calling "/usr/bin/git" explicitly will get your brew-managed one. But my take is, installing git implies you're taking ownership of git on your system. Worries about unknown processes using an older, alternate version of git, might be misplaced. I recommend keeping up to date w/ git versions (for security, not just features), and managing it yourself. Homebrew makes this easy. /$0.02

Comment: This didn't work for me, to undo it, just do: sudo mv /usr/bin/git-apple /usr/bin/git . Juan Diego Gonzales's comment worked. (basically, follow the accepted answer then restart terminal).

Comment: Even with `which git` pointing to `/usr/local/bin/git`, this didn't work for me. To solve this, I had to uninstall the GitHub Mac app.

Comment: MacOS 10.12.5: `sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-apple

mv: rename /usr/bin/git to /usr/bin/git-apple: Operation not permitted`

Comment: These days it seems homebrew puts itself at the "front" of the PATH so hopefully no longer needed :)

Comment: Just use `brew doctor`. In 2020, it recommended `brew link —overwrite git`

Comment: I was having the same issue, but installing OhMyZsh seemed to solve it, and put `/usr/local/bin/git:` before `/usr/bin:`. In hindsight, maybe all I needed to do was start a new terminal session!

Comment: Use `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` to put homebrew git to the leading position in system PATH.

Answer (score 27):

I tried this and it works for me.

```
brew link --overwrite git
```

Comment: As of April 2023, this worked on M2.

Answer (score 16):

Once you've installed the latest git via brew (`brew install git`), run this one-liner (as suggested by `brew doctor`) if it isn't already there:

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**Then quit Terminal an open it again** (restart your bash session). You need to do this even if your PATH was already correct, as ZSH and Bash cache the contents of PATH (see the documentation on the built-in command `hash`).

That should fix things really fast.

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer?

Comment: In my case, I didn't know I had to restart Terminal, so that part may help some people. Is faster than the accepted because of the one liner. If it's a competition I think my answer is misplaced. Otherwise I think it contributes. (Tell me if you want me to make an edit instead of this).

Comment: You do that one liner when you install Homebrew

Comment: I found this answer helpful. Restarting the terminal is a non-obvious issue for many people unfamiliar with the workings of .bash_profile, and a gentle reminder for the rest of us.

Comment: @JuanDiegoGonzales Excellent observation! I was wondering the exact same thing after I installed git and didn't know why. After the **cache** hint, I did a bit more research: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5609/52921

Comment: These days it seems homebrew puts itself at the "front" of the PATH so hopefully no longer needed :)

Answer (score 3):

When you type

```
git --version
```

in Terminal.app or console, your comment on another question indicated the version it returns is the git in /usr/bin/git

If you installed Xcode 4.5 (and newer), and type

```
xcrun git --version
```

in Terminal.app or console, the version it returns is the git in the Xcode app bundle.

If you are using Homebrew to install and update git, the simplest solution is to

1. make sure you have admin rights as you'll be asked for the password for the admin
2. rename the original location by renaming it using mv. For example

   sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-ORIGINAL
3. create a soft link using 'ln -s' to the git binary you installed with Homebrew.

Note that MattDMo has a better solution in the comments.

Comment: Please don't do this - you really shouldn't be messing around with `/usr/bin`, as it's possible that other programs you don't even know about depend on vagaries associated with a particular version. The easiest solution, without moving anything, is to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH` environment variable before `/usr/bin` - IIRC, homebrew installs to `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 3):

When you use `brew install git` for the installation, notice that it install `git` under:

```sh
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.29.2: 1,480 files, 39.7MB
```

You will also get an error, which appears earlier in the log and probably you missed it:

```sh
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/git-2.29.2.big_sur.bottle.t
Already downloaded: /Users/chadjinik/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/08165d120fcebc7823c487a6778b2ea0e67fd2cd9177d6e7d656268f474ab5da--git-2.29.2.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring git-2.29.2.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz

Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/git
Target /usr/local/bin/git
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/git'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite git
```

Just run:

```sh
brew link --overwrite git
```

and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Install git with brew, the run this.

`brew link --force git`

Close and reopen terminal to run `which git`.

Comment: How does that change the default path?

Comment: This worked for me to override xcode's git.

Comment: I got an error when running this but `brew link --overwrite git` worked

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename the original git by apple in `/usr/bin/` to e. g. git-org since `/usr/bin` is normally before `/usr/local/bin` in your path directory where the brew stuff is.

So:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo mv git git-org
```

and do not forget to link the brew git

```
brew link git
```

This assumes that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` environment variable. If you still have problem try to run

```
brew doctor
```

and fix the problems mentioned there.

Comment: Don;t rename or chnage things in /usr/bin as it could break Apple thigs and they will get chnaged when you do a system or XCode update. use the path which is what it is designed for,

Comment: I think it would be much easier to add `/usr/local/bin` (homebrew's install directory, IIRC) to the `$PATH` ahead of `/usr/bin` instead of mucking around with renaming and backing up, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple alias to avoid changing path:

```
alias git=/usr/local/bin/git
```

Comment: Yep! This is what I ended up doing too. I didn't want to change the PATH precedence or any other hacky stuff.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me. even changing path didn't work for me - possibly related to Xcode Command Line Tools

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I ran `brew doctor` and I saw this:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause formulae that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
git
```

Of course I run `brew link git`. Then I got:

```
Error: Could not symlink bin/git
Target /usr/local/bin/git
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/git'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite git

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run git
```

I ran `brew link --overwrite git` **and it worked!**

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing git from git-scm.com directly and would want to use the latest downloaded git instead of apple(old) version of git.

1. Install git from git-scm.com
2. Most probably new git will be installed in `/usr/local/bin/git`
3. Try `git --version`, if it returns Apple old version of git then proceed below
4. `cd ~` (change directory to your home directory)
5. type `vi .bashrc`
6. Use `i` (to insert text in vi editor)
7. If you find a line with `export PATH.......`, press enter on top of the export and type the following: `export PATH=/usr/local/:$PATH` (Pay extreme caution with `PATH` variable do not mess it up else it will cause problems for your OS)
   (hopefully new git should be installed in `/usr/local/git`)
8. Press esc
9. Enter `:wq` (to save the `.bashrc` file)
10. Exit out of terminal and start new terminal
11. Now try `git --version` (you should see new version)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on where your git comes from.  Xcode brings a version for example, maybe that is upfront in your path.

Maybe typing

```
which git
```

will show where the old one is.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried many things including all of this post's answers.  Finally I was able to get brew's version of git to run instead of Xcode's by simply deleting Xcode's additional tools folder:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: Those 'command line tools' are needed to install some Homebrew packages (when they need to be built from source).