# How to upgrade system default vim?

Tags: macos, vi

Finally, vim 8.0 has been [released](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases)! However, the pre-installed vim is vim 7.3 on my system(OS X El Capitan), and I want to upgrade it to the newest 8.0 version.

So how can I do this without messing things up? Would it be a good idea to simply override the vim in `/usr/bin/vim`? And what about compiling it from source?

Comment: Basically any command line tool works like http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93002/how-to-properly-update-git-on-mac or http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231347/5472

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Get the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)<sup>*</sup> package manager.

Install `vim` formula (as of today it is Vim 8.0.2) with:

```
brew install vim
```

Check the messages it produced for any manual actions you might be required to perform, although with Vim formula there should be no issues.

One more thing you should do is to check your environment variables for those that might contain a full path to the system `vi`/`vim`, like `EDITOR` and update them to use the `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

---

If you had Homebrew already installed, before running the install command, update the local repository with:

```
brew update
```

If you had Vim already installed with Homebrew (or if in the future you'd like to upgrade the Vim version), then run:

```
brew upgrade vim
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Homebrew is an open-source, actively maintained package manager for Mac OS X. It keeps the packages in `/usr/local/Cellar` folder by default. It stores links to the executable files `/usr/local/bin` and puts this directory ahead of system directories in the `PATH` environment variable. Your `/usr/bin/vim` can thus be left alone.

Homebrew will also take care of all the paths and dependencies for installed packages.

Comment: works for me. I had to add /usr/local/bin/vim to my PATH environment variable

Comment: For me it says, `Error: vim 8.0.1650_1 already installed` when I do `brew upgrade vim`

Comment: @R11G, you can `brew reinstall vim` if you're already on the most current version

Answer (score 4):

You can install vim with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) overriding the current system's vim with the `--with-override-system-vi`:

```
brew install vim -- --with-override-system-vi
```

Remember to **restart your terminal after that** to make sure the new symbolic links work as expected.

Comment: This option "--with-override-system-vi" doesn't seem exist.

Comment: The option "--with-override-system-vi" was removed in this PR https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/34421